# C++/CLI: Unresolved tokens & external symbols in Windows Forms app (LNK2001 & LNK2020)

Tags: c++, forms, visual-c++

**Background about my project:**

This time in my college's project, I have to create a Windows Forms application (info about the tools is explained at the bottom). And this application can train its neural networks to recognize images of dogs and their names (the names are assigned to the data within this application).

In the application, I have three forms: the main form (like a main menu), the Training form, and the Recognition form.

And when I start this application, I want these three forms to access the same global data, which I put in files `Globals.h` and `Globals.cpp`. I thought of initializing these globals in the main form, and I want to use and update these globals outside of the main form (the Training and Recognition forms).

Below are the codes for these globals:

`Globals.h` code:

```
#pragma once

#include <fann.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Globals {

public:
    static fann *ann;
    static map<string, string> nameMap;
    static int pictureCount;

public:
    static void initializeNeuralNetwork();
    static void insertNewDog(string /*output*/, string /*name*/);
    static string getNameOfDog(string /*output*/);
    static void incrementPictureCount();
    static fann * getAnn();
    static void trainNeuralNetwork(struct fann_train_data *data, int max_epochs,
                                               int epochs_between_reports,
                                               float desired_error);
    static void saveNeuralNetwork();
    static int getPictureCount();

};
```

`Globals.cpp` code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Globals.h"

using namespace std;

void Globals::initializeNeuralNetwork() {
    ann = fann_create_from_file("ann.net");
    if (!ann) {
        ann = fann_create_standard(3, 49, 38, 8);
    }

    fann_set_activation_function_layer(ann, FANN_SIGMOID, 0);
    fann_set_activation_function_layer(ann, FANN_SIGMOID, 1);
    fann_set_activation_function_layer(ann, FANN_SIGMOID, 2);

    pictureCount = 0;
}

void Globals::insertNewDog(string output, string name) {
    nameMap.insert( pair<string, string>(output, name) );
}

string Globals::getNameOfDog(string output) {
    if (nameMap.empty()) return "";

    string result = (nameMap.count(output)) ? nameMap[output] : "ERROR";
    return result;
}

fann * Globals::getAnn() {
    return ann;
}

void Globals::trainNeuralNetwork(struct fann_train_data *data, 
        int max_epochs, int epochs_between_reports, float desired_error) {

    fann_train_on_data(ann, data, max_epochs, epochs_between_reports, desired_error);
}

void Globals::saveNeuralNetwork() {
    fann_save(ann, "ann.net");
}

void Globals::incrementPictureCount() {
    pictureCount++;
}

int Globals::getPictureCount() {
    return pictureCount;
}
```

**Problem:**

I've tried to search for a problem similar to mine, but haven't found any so far. The problem is, when I tried to invoke the methods of these globals in the Training form, I got these LNK* errors from the output when I tried to run the application:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: DogBreedRecognizer-Group6, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  DogBreedRecognizer-Group6.cpp
1>c:\users\baskoro indrayana\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\dogbreedrecognizer-group6\dogbreedrecognizer-group6\TrainingForm.h(654): warning C4996: 'itoa': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C++ conformant name: _itoa. See online help for details.
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(867) : see declaration of 'itoa'
1>c:\users\baskoro indrayana\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\dogbreedrecognizer-group6\dogbreedrecognizer-group6\TrainingForm.h(664): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'int' to 'fann_type', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\baskoro indrayana\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\dogbreedrecognizer-group6\dogbreedrecognizer-group6\TrainingForm.h(703): warning C4305: 'argument' : truncation from 'double' to 'float'
1>Globals.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A000023) "public: static class std::map<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const ,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > > Globals::nameMap" (?nameMap@Globals@@$$Q2V?$map@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@U?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@@std@@@2@@std@@A)
1>Globals.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A000028) "public: static int Globals::pictureCount" (?pictureCount@Globals@@$$Q2HA)
1>Globals.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A00002D) "public: static struct fann * Globals::ann" (?ann@Globals@@$$Q2PAUfann@@A)
1>Globals.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int Globals::pictureCount" (?pictureCount@Globals@@$$Q2HA)
1>Globals.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct fann * Globals::ann" (?ann@Globals@@$$Q2PAUfann@@A)
1>Globals.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::map<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const ,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > > Globals::nameMap" (?nameMap@Globals@@$$Q2V?$map@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@U?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@@std@@@2@@std@@A)
1>C:\Users\Baskoro Indrayana\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DogBreedRecognizer-Group6\Debug\DogBreedRecognizer-Group6.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

If you want to see the code where I invoke the methods of this Globals class, here are the codes to the forms:

- [Main form](http://pastebin.com/QhD0RDED)
- [Training form](http://pastebin.com/bUDtqz8e)
- Recognition form: incomplete -- I haven't worked on this form or called any of the Globals' methods there, yet.

**So, my questions are:**

1. What is causing these linker errors? And how do I get to solve them in this case?
2. I'm wondering if there is a better way to organize the data for the ANN, in a way that three of the forms can use and update them (and use the updated values, as well.)

**Tools used:** Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition (I had to use this because my college assignment instructed us to, so there's no option to use any other IDEs/languages/tools, if you'd ask.)

That is all from me. I'll be waiting for your answer on my problem, and I appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/811-static-member-variables/

Comment: @HansPassant Oh okay, I just forgot to initialize the static member variables from within Globals.cpp. Thanks for the link!